# How can i put bullet points on all listed items (collapsible content) DAWN

Tags: css, shopify, liquid

im trying to get bullet points on all listed items on that tab (collapsible content) on dawn theme with shopify. But i managed to get that just on first item, you can check here with preview url: https://1524t2hmp2urghsm-53196980409.shopifypreview.com

and here is part of code reference this issue:

```
{%- when 'collapsible_tab' -%}
           <div class="product__acordion_container">
            <div class="product__accordion accordion" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
              <details id="Details-{{ block.id }}-{{ section.id }}">
                <summary>
                  <div class="summary__title">
                    {% render 'icon-accordion', icon: block.settings.icon %}
                    <h2 class="h4 accordion__title">
                      {{ block.settings.heading | default: block.settings.page.title }}
                    </h2>
                  </div>
                  {% render 'icon-caret' %}
                </summary>
                <ul>
                 <li id="ProductAccordion-{{ block.id }}-{{ section.id }}">{{ block.settings.content }}</li>
                  {{ block.settings.page.content }}
                </ul>
              </details>
            </div>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://ed.codes/blogs/tutorials/add-a-youtube-video-inside-collapsible-row-block-accordion-on-shopify-product-page use this vid to add the element to the block

then add a container in the liquid

```
<p> 
{% if product.metafields.custom.METAFIELDNAME %}
<div class="product-features__features Container">       
{{product.metafields.custom.METAFIELDNAME}}
    </div>
{% endif %} 
</p>
```

and then link to the HTML formatted list as a multi-line text meta field.